# Модификация ON UPDATE RESTRICT триггера

Tags: mysql, update, триггер

Возникла необходимость модифицировать триггер, который обеспечивает целостность связи при операции UPDATE в родительской таблице. Движок - MyISAM.

Есть 2 таблицы: Developers (потомок) и Engines (родитель).

Таблица Developers:

```
CREATE TABLE `developers` (
`id_developer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_engine` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`founding_date` date NOT NULL,
`earnings` float(6,2) NOT NULL,
`developer_name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_developer`),
KEY `fk_Developers_Engine_id_name` (`fk_engine`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Таблица Engines:

```
CREATE TABLE `engines` (
`id_engine` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`engine_name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`engine_description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_engine`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Триггер:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER
gamestore_myisam.updateRestrict_myisam_engines
BEFORE UPDATE
ON gamestore_myisam.engines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gamestore_myisam.developers WHERE fk_engine = old.id_engine)
!=0
THEN
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Cannot update a child row:
foreign key constraint fails!';
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Суть проблемы: данный триггер не позволяет обновить id_engine таблицы Engines, если этот id_engine содержится в fk_engine таблицы Developers так как в этом случае будет нарушена целосность связи. Но если мне необходимо обновить поле engine_name или engine_description этого id_engine в таблице Engines, то триггер не даст этого сделать.

Как модифицировать триггер чтобы он по прежнему не давал обновлять id_engine в таблице Engines, но при этом была возможность обновлять поля engine_name и engine_description этого id_engine?

Comment: Наверное, сначала надо всё же сравнить OLD.id_engine и NEW.id_engine, и делать остальные проверки только в случае, если оно меняется...

Comment: @Akina, спасибо большое

Comment: @Akina Возникло ещё одно осложнение. Если я добавлю новую запись в таблицу Engines и при этом она не будет связана с таблицей Developers. И мне нужно обновить id этой новой записи, то сравнение old.id_engine и new.id_engine не подходит. Как быть в этой ситуации? Грубо говоря для связанных id_engine c таблицей Developers нельзя менять значение id_engine, а для не связанных - можно. И при этом поля engine_name и engine_description можно редактировать как для связанных так и для не связанных.

Comment: По-моему, Вы ошибаетесь. Вы пытаетесь решать ИСХОДНУЮ задачу неверными средствами - выбор использования триггера не может устранить причину проблемы. Я рекомендую пока забыть о триггере, и создать новый вопрос, где полностью описать технологию и имеющуюся сейчас структуру. Значительная часть запретов, которые Вы хотите реализовать триггером, реализуется правильной структурой хранения данных и ограничениями (условными и внешних ключей), которая сейчас явно реализуется на стороне клиента, и, как следствие, получается криво.